# Error while loading an AMD module inside index.android.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, requirejs, music21

I have a local module written in require.js ([music21j](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21j) for the curious). I don't know exactly how to load the module using 'import' or whether it will be packed by the packager, but here is how I attempted to import it:

1. `react-native init AwesomeProject`
2. `cd AwesomeProject`
3. `react-native run-android`
4. Android emulator shows the default "Welcome to React Native!" message.
5. Assuming I'll need Require.js NPM module in order to load the module, I installed require.js module as follows: `npm install requirejs`.
6. Edited index.android.js to add the following line: `enter code here
   import requirejs from 'requirejs';`
7. Back to android emulator. App display got refreshed automatically (hot loading?) and now it shows the following error
   [image]

I'm still learning react/react-native. I think my problem is a lack of understanding for how the app packager works. However, I'd really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The version of music21j you were working with didn't play well with things other than requireJS.  The newest version uploaded a few days ago should work fine if you have ES6 and you load the src/loadModules.js as the main interface and load the dependencies (jQuery, Vexflow, MIDI) separately.  Let me know how it works.  I've only done a browser context.

Answer (score 0):

Remove RequireJS. There is absolutely no need for it. React Native provides module loading out of the box.

Comment: I attempted to get rid of requirejs. 1) uninstalled RequireJS 2) removed "require requirejs from 'requirejs'. 3) added require(['./public/music21j/src/music21']. Now the emulator displays `Requiring unknown module "./public/music21j/src/music21.js"`. And yes, I confirm that `public/music21j/src/music21.js` exists.

Comment: Where is the file you are requiring from located? In react native generally you would leave off the extension but I doubt that is causing an issue.